# Phrase meaning: every now and then vs every once in a while

Tags: phrase-meaning

I would like to know whether there is a difference in meaning of the following phrases:
1. Every now and then;
2. Every once in a while.
I know that they both mean occasionally, but is that all? There are no any other differences?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/every+once+in+a+while

Comment: Funny that you ask the question.., I was going through my NASB version bible and looking at the historical books, the books of 1,2 Samuel, 1,2 Kings, 1, 2 Chronicles and the prophets.. Almost every single chapter begins with the words ' Now', 'And' & ''Then'.. Not only the chapters, but most of the paragraphs as well.. Now I'm thinking.., maybe there is a broader context to the application and use of these particular words..? Then again, maybe it is purely a random expression because it is so universal..? I noticed that I have applied the same principle in the above paragraph. ‼️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, there is no real difference that I can see. I'd love to see an example, in context, where there is a difference in meaning, but I'm not seeing one at all. Further, I would say that the two phrases are equivalent as far as how commonly they are used and how easily they will be understood.

At this point, I will say that they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you, Jolene! As far as “how easily they will be understood” I can bet that’s for natives.

Comment: It's fair to say that "from the point of view of the native speaker" is the ONLY way I can answer questions with any authority. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both of these two phrases mean occasionally
But I think that the periods in once in a while are shorter than them in every now and then.

Although the time is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].