# Something + "now and then" + colon + "a journey...": just standard adverbs?

Tags: idioms, adverbs, time

I noticed from some<sup>1</sup> *Books* [output](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once%20in%20a%20while%2Cnow%20and%20then%2Cevery%20once%20in%20a%20while%2Cevery%20now%20and%20then%2Cevery%20so%20often&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20in%20a%20while%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnow%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20once%20in%20a%20while%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20now%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20so%20often%3B%2Cc0) some entries([example](https://books.google.com/books?id=gEeyAAAAIAAJ&q=%22now%20and%20then%22&dq=%22now%20and%20then%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iE0rVfvOLYSQyQTXpYDgBQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAzge)) where "now" and "then" are used as adverbs to compare something now with something then(not unlike "*before and after*"); or to identify a period of time when events related to a person/topic/place unfold. Often this appears within titles and is followed by a colon:

> [a person/topic/place] **Now and then:** *the journey from Z to A/a review of
>   an era in the field of strange*... etc.

Obviously in context this doesn't mean "occasionally". At the same time it seems to "mean a lot" with very little, so to speak, as in it's shorter/simpler than *since then until now*, and the order is not chronological as it would be with [*then and now*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=now%20and%20then%2Cthen%20and%20now&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnow%20and%20then%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthen%20and%20now%3B%2Cc0).

---

Is that simply considered the literal meaning of those adverbs modifying the preceding noun? Or is that some kind of competing "idiom" as in "*the now and the then*" of something; are those two adverbs some kind of group ? Why is the preposition "*of*" not required between the noun and "*now and then*"; and why isn't the syntax rather "*Now and then*: [a person/topic/place], *the journey...* etc."?

---

<sub>1. I was curious about the usage of a few idioms which use the "*every*" determiner to introduce a frequency i.e. *[every](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/every%20now%20and%20then) + [now and then](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/now%20and%20then)* (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/121259), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18976)).</sub>

Comment: I reads *[a person/topic/place] now and then* (I feel weird to capitalize only N but not t, so I write *now* in the lowercase) as "(how) [a person/topic/place] (is (like)) now, and (how) [a person/topic/place] (is (like)) then".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will find these in titles of works. Essentially, it is referring to points in time: *now*, the present, and *then*, the past.

These works will usually compare or contrast phenomena or behaviour in the two time periods.

It's not an adverb, it's a stylistic choice of title.

Comment: Thank you! So just the literal meaning styled a certain way in a tittle. Any comment on the order i.e. now and then vs. then and now; any reason we start with the present? I also gather punctuation has no real impact here?

Comment: @Amphiteóth: I think it could only work with a colon or an em dash. The reason for this is that they are both used as conjunctions when one _elaborates_ - that is, when one restates something, in a different way. I'd also say that it's probably a matter of proximity - _now_ and _then_, but it might just be a strange quirk of the language.