# occasionally vs every once in a while

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, phrase-choice, adverbial-phrases

Following [Phrase meaning: every now and then vs every once in a while](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18976/phrase-meaning-every-now-and-then-vs-every-once-in-a-while), what's the difference between "occasionally" and "every once in a while" in formal writing?

E.g.:

> Occasionally, I ask the audience whether the slides so far are clear.
>
> Every once in a while, I ask the audience whether the slides so far are clear.

Comment: I am not a writer, but there isn't much difference. I would say that "every once in a while" is less often and less periodic than "occasionally". You might also check "from time to time".

Comment: I don't perceive a difference in frequency, but "every once in a while" is more colloquial and hence has slightly different connotations. For instance, I'd be more likely to use "occasionally" of a bad thing happening.

Answer (score 0):

These are very similar. As the commenter mentioned, 'I would say that "every once in a while" is less often and less periodic than "occasionally".'